# Evaluate $\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{1 + A\sin(\theta) + B\cos(\theta)}\, \mathrm{d}\theta \ \text{ for }\ A,B \ll 1$

Tags: integration, trigonometry

I need to evaluate the definite integral $$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{1 + A\sin(\theta) + B\cos(\theta)}\, \mathrm{d}\theta  \ \text{    for various}\ A,B \text{; with}\ A,B\ll1.$$

[Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2F%5B1+%2B+A*sin+theta+%2B+B*cos+theta%5D+dtheta) provides the following indefinite general solution:-

$$\int \frac{1}{1 + A\sin(\theta) + B\cos(\theta)}\, \mathrm{d}\theta =  -(2/K) \tanh^{-1} \left( \frac{A-(B-1)\tan(\theta/2)}{K}\right) $$
where $K = \sqrt{A^2 + B^2 -1}$.

But I am having trouble checking it for the simple case when $A=B=0$ when I would expect the answer to be given by:-
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{1 + 0 + 0}\, \mathrm{d}\theta = 2\pi.$$

I have approached the Wolfram Alpha solution thus:-
$$ -\frac{2}{K}\tanh^{-1} \left( \frac{\tan(2\pi/2)}{K}\right) +\frac{2}{K} \tanh^{-1} \left( \frac{\tan(0/2)}{K}\right) $$

$$ -\frac{2}{K} \tanh^{-1} \left( \frac{\tan(\pi)}{K}\right) +\frac{2}{K} \tanh^{-1} \left( \frac{\tan(0)}{K}\right) $$

$$ -\frac{2}{K}\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{0}{K}\right) +\frac{2}{K} \tanh^{-1} \left( \frac{0}{K}\right) $$

which gives the result of zero.

I presume this error comes from trying to integrate across the range $0, 2\pi$ where the $\tan$ function has singularities at $\pi/2$ and $3\pi/2$.

However when I try and break the integration into the three continuous ranges $0,\pi/2$ and $\pi/2,3\pi/2$ and $3\pi/2,2\pi$ I am still getting a result of zero thus:-

$$ -\frac{2}{K} \tanh^{-1} \left( \frac{\tan(2\pi/2)}{K}\right) +\frac{2}{K} \tanh^{-1} \left( \frac{\tan(3\pi/4)}{K}\right) + $$
$$ -\frac{2}{K} \tanh^{-1} \left( \frac{\tan(3\pi/4)}{K}\right) +\frac{2}{K} \tanh^{-1} \left( \frac{\tan(\pi/4)}{K}\right) +$$
$$ -\frac{2}{K} \tanh^{-1} \left( \frac{\tan(\pi/4)}{K}\right) +\frac{2}{K} \tanh^{-1} \left( \frac{\tan(0)}{K}\right) $$

leading to
$$ -\frac{2}{K} \tanh^{-1} \left( \frac{0}{K}\right) +\frac{2}{K} \tanh^{-1}\left( \frac{-1}{K}\right) + $$
$$ -\frac{2}{K} \tanh^{-1} \left( \frac{-1}{K}\right) +\frac{2}{K} \tanh^{-1} \left(\frac{1}{K}\right) +$$
$$ -\frac{2}{K} \tanh^{-1} \left( \frac{1}{K}\right) +\frac{2}{K} \tanh^{-1}\left( \frac{0}{K}\right) $$

which gives the same result of zero.

I would be grateful if somebody could tell me where I am going wrong here?

---

EDIT 1: I have accepted the solution provided kindly by Dr. MV.
I have posted a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2230692/evaluate-left-2-k-tanh-1-fraca-b-1-tan-theta-2k-right-0) which seeks to understand where my original evaluation of the definite integrand goes wrong.

---

EDIT 2: In the [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2230692/evaluate-left-2-k-tanh-1-fraca-b-1-tan-theta-2k-right-0)  comments from user mickep pointed out that the wrong partitions had been used in the original evaluation. Using the correct partitions ($0...\pi$) and ($\pi...2\pi$) leads to the correct answer, for $A=B=0$, of $2\pi$ (as described in my self-answer to that same question).

---

EDIT 3: It was pointed out by user mickep in comments to the [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2230692/evaluate-left-2-k-tanh-1-fraca-b-1-tan-theta-2k-right-0) that the Wolfram Alpha solution

$$ -\left(\frac{2}{K_1}\right) \text{arctanh}\left( \frac{A-(B-1)\tan(\theta/2)}{K_1}\right) $$
where $K_1= \sqrt{A^2 + B^2 -1}$.

is not as friendly as an alternative solution (reported by user mickep) which is:

$$ +\left(\frac{2}{K_2}\right) \arctan  \left( \frac{A+(1-B)\tan(\theta/2)}{K_2}\right) $$
where $K_2 = \sqrt{1 - A^2 - B^2}$.

Comment: Shall one assume $A^2+B^2>1$, so that $K$ is real?

Comment: @Math-fun sorry but no. A and B are both very very small.  I don't think it is too big a problem because at the end of the day K only appears as even (negative) powers so we don't have to consider imaginaries.

Comment: What about the K outside of the tanh^-1? Did you include that as part of the series cancellation? If not then perhaps that's an issue

Comment: @WIll Craig After expanding all the K terms in the expansions are negative and odd.  Then when I apply the outer K term all the K terms becaome negative and even.  In the simplified case with A=B=0 K becomes $i$ all the K terms become -1.

Comment: Then I don't know - this is weird.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution

Comment: @Will Craig. I was wrong about the effect of complex K terms inside the arctanh function - I cannot simply cancel them.  My answer (somewhere below) explores this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the integral of interest fails to converge if $\sqrt{A^2+B^2}\ge 1$.  So, we restrict $A$ and $B$ such that $\sqrt{A^2+B^2}< 1$.

Then, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{1+A\sin(\theta)+B\cos(\theta)}\,d\theta&=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{A^2+B^2} \cos(\theta-\arctan(A/B)}\,d\theta\\\\
&=\int_{-\arctan(A/B)}^{2\pi-\arctan(A/B)}\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{A^2+B^2} \cos(\theta)}\,d\theta\\\\
&=2\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{A^2+B^2} \cos(\theta)}\,d\theta\tag1
\end{align}$$

where we exploited both the $2\pi$-periodicity and the evenness of the cosine function.

Next, we enforce the [Weierstrass Substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution),  $ t=\tan(\theta/2)$, in $(1)$ to obtain

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{1+A\sin(\theta)+B\cos(\theta)}\,d\theta&=4\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(1+\sqrt{A^2+B^2})+(1-\sqrt{A^2+B^2})t^2}\,dt\\\\
&=\frac{4}{1-\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\frac{1+\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}{1-\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}+t^2}\,dt \tag 2\\\\
&=\frac{4}{1-\sqrt{A^2+B^2}} \left.\left(\frac{\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{1-\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}}{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}}t\right)}{\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}{1-\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}}}\right)\right|_{0}^{\infty}  \tag 3\\\\
&=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{1-A^2-B^2}}  \tag 4
\end{align}$$

---

Note that we could have written $(2)$ as

$$\begin{align}
\frac{4}{1-\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\frac{1+\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}{1-\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}+t^2}\,dt&=\frac{4}{1-\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{t^2-\frac{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}+1}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}-1}}\,dt\\\\
&=\frac{4}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}-1}\left.\left( \frac{\text{arctanh}\left(\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}-1}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}+1}}t\right)}{\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}+1}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}-1}}}\right)\right|_{0}^\infty\\\\
&=\frac{4}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}-1}\,\left(\frac{i\pi/2}{\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}+1}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}-1}}}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{1-A^2-B^2}}
\end{align}$$

as expected!

Comment: How do you transform from $A \sin theta + B \cos theta$ at the beginning?

Comment: Steve, I've edited.

Comment: Thanks but I still don't follow that first equation (my maths level = high school).

Comment: Steve, the addition angle formula for the cosine function is $\cos(a-b)=\cos(a)\cos(b)+\sin(a)\sin(b)$.  Let $a=\theta$ and $b=\arctan(A/B)$.  Then, we see that $$\cos(\theta -\arctan(A/B))=\cos(\arctan(A/B))\cos(\theta)+\sin(\arctan(A/B))\sin(\theta)=\frac{B}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}\cos(\theta)+\frac{A}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}\sin(\theta)$$

Comment: Many thanks, I understand that now :) Next I need to study the Weierstrass Substitution.

Comment: You're certainly welcome.  I've embedded a link to an article on the substitution.  -Mark

Comment: And feel free to up vote and best vote as you see fit.

Comment: I have read the link and see how cos(theta)= (1-t^2)/(1+t^2) but I don't see how you get the RHS of the equation on the line before (2).

Comment: Steve, recall that $d\theta = \frac{2}{1+t^2}\,dt$.  Now, just a little arithmetic you will be able to obtain $(2)$.

Comment: Mark, many thanks. I've made it to (3) but, apart from $arctan(\infty)=\pi/2$  I cant see how to get to the final expression: (4).  Are you approximating?

Comment: Steve, you're welcome.  There is no approximation.  We have $$\frac{4}{1-\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\sqrt{1-\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}}{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}}\right)=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{(1-\sqrt{A^2+B^2})(1+\sqrt{A^2+B^2})}}=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{1-A^2-B^2}}$$

Comment: Mark, I get it now. Many thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

When one of $A$ and $B$ is non-zero, then one way to figure this out for yourself is to put 
$$A \colon= r \cos \beta \ \mbox{ and } \ B \colon= r \sin \beta,$$
where 
$$r = \sqrt{A^2 + B^2} \ \mbox{ and } \ B \tan \beta = A.$$ 
Then 
$$ 
\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{1+ A \sin \theta + B \cos \theta } \mathrm{d} \theta &= \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{1+r\sin(\beta + \theta) } \mathrm{d} \theta.
\end{align}
$$
Can you take it from here?

As one trick, you can put 
$$z = \tan \frac{\beta + \theta}{2}.$$
Then $$\sin (\beta+\theta) = \frac{2z}{1+z^2} \ \mbox{ and } \ \mathrm{d} \theta = \frac{2 \mathrm{d} z}{1+z^2}.$$

When $\theta = 0$, $z= \tan \beta/2$, and when $\theta = 2\pi$, $z= \tan \left( \pi+ \beta/2 \right) = \tan \beta/2$.

So, 
$$ 
\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{1+ A \sin \theta + B \cos \theta } \mathrm{d} \theta &= \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{1+r\sin(\beta + \theta) } \mathrm{d} \theta  \\
&= 2 \int_{\tan \beta/2}^{\tan \beta/2} \frac{1}{1+2rz+z^2} \mathrm{d} \theta \\ 
&= 0
\end{align}
$$

For $A = B=0$, the answer is $2\pi$, as you've correctly found out.

Comment: thanks but I'm not sure where to go with this.

Comment: I see how $=0$ (your penultimate line) arises from the previous line.  But how is the general solution  $=0$ consistent with the $A=B=0$ special case solution of $= 2\pi$.?

Answer (score 1):

A solution through complex analysis is missing, so I will provide one.
 By De Moivre's identities the given integral equals

$$ \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{e^{i\theta} d\theta} {e^{i\theta}+ \frac{A-Bi}{2}e^{2i\theta}+\frac{A+Bi}{2}}=-i\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{dz}{\frac{A-Bi}{2}z^2+z+\frac{A+Bi}{2}}$$
and that is $2\pi$ times the sum of the residues of the function $\frac{1}{\frac{A-Bi}{2}z^2+z+\frac{A+Bi}{2}}$ at its poles inside the unit circle. The poles lies at $\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1-A^2-B^2}}{A-iB}$ and the computation is straightforward.

Comment: Thanks. This is way above my head but can I ask whether it provides a solution for when A=B=0?

Comment: @steveOw: of course. If $A=B=0$ the initial integral simply equals $$-i\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{dz}{z} = -i(2\pi i) = 2\pi $$ as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Under $A,B \ll 1$, approximate the integral by expanding the integrand
\begin{align}
&\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{1 + A\sin \theta+ B\cos\theta}\, {d}\theta \\
\approx &\int_0^{2\pi}\left[1 -( A\sin \theta+ B\cos\theta)+ (A\sin \theta+ B\cos\theta)^2\right] d\theta \\
=&\int_0^{2\pi}\left(1 +\frac {A^2}2+  \frac {B^2}2\right)d\theta =\pi(2+A^2+B^2)\\
\end{align}
where all the vanishing terms are disregarded.

Comment: Thanks this is a reasonable answer to the question in the title.  But (as detailed in the text of the question) I was looking particularly for a proof of the Wolfram Alpha indefinite general solution in the case when $A=B=0$.