# Evaluate $\left[ -(2/K) \tanh^{-1} ( \frac{A-(B-1)\tan(\theta/2)}{K}) \right]_0^{2\pi}$ where $K = \sqrt{A^2 + B^2 -1}$ and $A^2 + B^2\ll 1$.

Tags: integration, geometry

I am having difficulty in evaluating the following integrand:
$$\left[ -\frac{2}{K}\tanh^{-1} \left( \frac{A-(B-1)\tan(\theta/2)}{K}\right)
\right]_0^{2\pi}$$
where $K = \sqrt{A^2 + B^2 -1}$ and   $A^2 + B^2\ll 1$.

---

To  evaluate the indefinite integral $I$ $$I = \int \frac{1}{1 + A\sin(\theta) + B\cos(\theta)}\, \mathrm{d}\theta \ \text{    for various}\ A,B \ll 1.$$

[Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2F%5B1+%2B+A*sin+theta+%2B+B*cos+theta%5D+dtheta) provides the following solution:-

$$I= -\frac{2}{K} \tanh^{-1} \left( \frac{A-(B-1)\tan(\theta/2)}{K}\right) $$
where $K = \sqrt{A^2 + B^2 -1}$.

In the simple case when $A=B=0$ the definite integral over the range $0...2\pi$ should obviously be given by:-
$$I_{A=B=0}=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{1 + 0 + 0}\, \mathrm{d}\theta = 2\pi.$$

This specific result has been confirmed by the restricted ( for $A^2+B^2<1$ ) Definite Solution
$$I=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{1 + A\cos(\theta) + B\sin(\theta)}\, \mathrm{d}\theta = 2\pi.$$
developed by [Dr. MV in his answer to my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2229374/evaluate-int-02-pi-frac11-a-sin-theta-b-cos-theta-mathrmd/2230636#2230636).

However I would like to know where my evaluation of the integrand is going wrong as I will need in future to apply a similar approach to other, more complex integrands for which I dont yet have Definite Solutions.

---

We might (naively) approach the Wolfram Alpha solution in the following way, noting that when $A=B=0$ so $K=i$, :-
$$I_{A=B=0}= \left[ -\frac{2}{i} \tanh^{-1} \left( \frac{\tan(\theta/2)}{i}\right) \right]_0^{\infty}$$
$$= -\frac{2}{i} \tanh^{-1} \left( \frac{\tan(2\pi/2)}{i}\right) +\frac{2}{i} \tanh^{-1} \left( \frac{\tan(0/2)}{i}\right) $$

$$ = -\frac{2}{i} \tanh^{-1} \left( \frac{\tan(\pi)}{i}\right) +\frac{2}{i} \tanh^{-1} \left( \frac{\tan(0)}{i}\right) $$

$$ = -\frac{2}{i} \tanh^{-1} \left( \frac{0}{i}\right) +\frac{2}{i} \tanh^{-1} \left( \frac{0}{i}\right) $$
$$ = 0.$$

but this is clearly incorrect.  I presume the error comes from trying to integrate across the range $0, 2\pi$ where the $\tan$ function has singularities at $\pi/2$ and $3\pi/2$.

---

So let us try and break the integration into the three continuous ranges $0...\pi/2$ and $\pi/2...3\pi/2$ and $3\pi/2...2\pi$ thus:-

$$I_{A=B=0}=$$
$$ -\frac{2}{i} \tanh^{-1} \left( \frac{\tan(2\pi/2)}{i}\right) - -\frac{2}{i} \tanh^{-1} \left( \frac{\tan(3\pi/4)}{i}\right) + $$
$$ -\frac{2}{i} \tanh^{-1} \left( \frac{\tan(3\pi/4)}{i}\right) - - \frac{2}{i} \tanh^{-1} \left( \frac{\tan(\pi/4)}{i}\right) +$$
$$ -\frac{2}{i} \tanh^{-1} \left( \frac{\tan(\pi/4)}{i}\right) - - \frac{2}{i} \tanh^{-1} \left( \frac{\tan(0)}{i}\right) $$

leading to
$$I_{A=B=0}=$$
$$ -\frac{2}{i} \tanh^{-1} \left( \frac{0}{i}\right) +\frac{2}{i}\tanh^{-1} \left( \frac{-1}{i}\right) + $$
$$ -\frac{2}{i} \tanh^{-1} \left( \frac{-1}{i}\right) +\frac{2}{i} \tanh^{-1} \left( \frac{1}{i}\right) +$$
$$ -\frac{2}{i} \tanh^{-1} \left( \frac{1}{i}\right) +\frac{2}{i}\tanh^{-1} \left( \frac{0}{i}\right) $$

Now
$\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{0}{i}\right) = 0$,  $\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{-1}{i}\right) = \frac{i\pi}{4}$,   and $\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{i}\right) = \frac{-i\pi}{4}$

and so

$$I_{A=B=0}=$$
$$ -\frac{2}{i} 0 +\frac{2}{i} \frac{i\pi}{4} + $$
$$ -\frac{2}{i} \frac{i\pi}{4}+\frac{2}{i} \frac{-i\pi}{4} +  $$
$$ -\frac{2}{i} \frac{-i\pi}{4}+\frac{2}{i} 0    $$

then
$$I_{A=B=0}= +\frac{2}{i} \frac{i\pi}{4} -\frac{2}{i}\frac{i\pi}{4}+\frac{2}{i} \frac{-i\pi}{4} -\frac{2}{i} \frac{-i\pi}{4}  $$

$$I_{A=B=0}=  \frac{2\pi}{4} -\frac{2\pi}{4} - \frac{2\pi}{4} + \frac{2\pi}{4}  $$

$$I_{A=B=0}= 0$$.

So we still get the wrong answer.  Clearly the right answer ($2 \pi$) could be obtained if all the minus signs were converted into plus signs, but I cant't find justification for doing that, as yet.

Any suggestions welcomed!

Comment: As $\theta$ runs from $0$ to $2\pi$, $\theta/2$ will run from $0$ to $\pi$. The only problem occurs when $\theta=\pi$. But why are you using the primitive in terms of the inverse of tanh and not tan, if I may ask?

Comment: What mickep said.  It's true that $\tan\theta$ has singularities at $\theta=\pm \pi/2, \pm 3\pi/2$, etc., but you aren't dealing with $\tan\theta$, you're dealing with $\tan(\theta/2)$.

Comment: @mickep Not sure what you mean by primitive, I got the expression from Wolfram Alpha here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2F%5B1+%2B+A*sin+theta+%2B+B*cos+theta%5D+dtheta

Comment: I suggest that you do a by-hand calculation. I get the primitive $$\frac{2}{\sqrt{1-A^2-B^2}}\arctan\Bigl(\frac{A+(1-B)\tan(\theta/2)}{\sqrt{1-A^2-B^2}}\Bigr)$$ which is much nicer to handle since everything is real. (You still have to do the partition into the intervals $(0,\pi)$ and $(\pi,2\pi)$, though.)

Comment: @mickep for A=B=0 and range 0...2$\pi$ by my calcs your formula gives $2 \arctan(0) - 2 \arctan(0) = 0$ when correct answer is $2 \pi$.

Comment: For the third time, you have to divide into $(0,\pi)$ and $(\pi,2\pi)$. Be careful at $\pi$ (you should take left and right limits).

Comment: @mickep. Ah thanks, clear now (I missed your previous edit about partitions). Gives expected answer $2\pi$. I just used arctan(tan(x)) = x so no quibbles at $\pi$. Your formula is indeed much nicer but beyond my ability to derive in this and forthcoming cases. Shame Wolfram doesnt give me that formula. I will review my partitions using the Wolfram formula.

Answer (score 0):

Following comments by user mickep let us look at correcting the partitions used...

So, to avoid operating across the singularity at $\frac{\pi}{2}$, let us break the integration into the two continuous ranges $0...\pi$ and $\pi...2\pi$ thus:-

$$I_{A=B=0}=$$
$$ -\left(\frac{2}{i}\right) \tanh^{-1} \left( \frac{\tan\left(2\pi/2\right)}{i}\right) - -\left(\frac{2}{i}\right) \tanh^{-1} \left( \frac{\tan\left(\pi/2\right)}{i}\right) + $$
$$ -\left(\frac{2}{i}\right) \tanh^{-1} \left( \frac{\tan\left(\pi/2\right)}{i}\right) - - \left(\frac{2}{i}\right) \tanh^{-1} \left( \frac{\tan\left(0\right)}{i}\right) +$$

leading to 
$$I_{A=B=0}=$$
$$ -\left(\frac{2}{i}\right) \tanh^{-1} \left( \frac{0}{i}\right) +\left(\frac{2}{i}\right) \tanh^{-1} \left( \frac{-\infty}{i}\right)  -\left(\frac{2}{i}\right) \tanh^{-1} \left( \frac{+\infty}{i}\right) +\left(\frac{2}{i}\right) \tanh^{-1} \left( \frac{0}{i}\right) $$

Now

$tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{0}{i}\right) = 0$,  $tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{-\infty}{i}\right) = \frac{i\pi}{2} $,   and $tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{\infty}{i}\right) = \frac{-i\pi}{2} $

and so

$$I_{A=B=0} = 0 +\left(\frac{2}{i}\right) \frac{i\pi}{2} -\left(\frac{2}{i}\right) \frac{-i\pi}{2} + 0 $$
$$I_{A=B=0} = \pi --\pi $$
$$I_{A=B=0} = 2\pi . $$

which is the expected answer.